# Почему Selenium не производит автоматический вход по cookie?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, auth

Не срабатывает автоматическая авторизация по cookie.
Есть 2 метода один соберает `cookie` в файл, другой парсит их и инжектит в WebDriver при последующих запусках.

```
public void writeCookiesToFile(WebDriver webDriver) {
    try (BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(new File(path)))) {
        for (Cookie cookie : webDriver.manage().getCookies()) {
            String data = format("%s;%s;%s;%s;%s;%s", cookie.getName(), cookie.getValue(),
                    cookie.getDomain(), cookie.getPath(), cookie.getExpiry(), cookie.isSecure());
            writer.write(data);
            writer.newLine();
        }
        writer.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void injectCookiesFromFile(WebDriver driver) {
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(line, ";");
            while (str.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String name = str.nextToken();
                String value = str.nextToken();
                String domain = str.nextToken();
                String path = str.nextToken();
                Date expiry = null;
                String date = str.nextToken();
                if (!(date).equals("null")) {
                    expiry = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000);
                }
                boolean isSecure = Boolean.parseBoolean(str.nextToken());
                driver.manage().addCookie(new Cookie(name, value, domain, path, expiry, isSecure));
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Вызов первого метода:

```
writeCookiesToFile(WebDriver driver)
```

Отрабатывается корректно, и `cookie` попадают в файл. Затем, при следующем запуске приложения, я вызываю:

```
injectCookiesFromFile(WebDriver driver)
```

и после этого вызываю `driver.get(url)` сайт открывается с запросом логина и пароля.

В общем не работает. То ли я не корректно записываю куки в файл используя `;` в качестве разделителя значений, то ли не верно парсю при чтении. Хотя я не вижу никаких ошибок, вроде все верно. Возможно проблемой является кнопка `запомнить меня`? Хотя при первой авторизации перед записью в файл она так-же успешно нажимается.

Помогите пожалуйста рабобраться в чем может быть ошибка. Спасибо.